# Creating a clickable area in HTML/CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this code that I created with some help:

I don't understand how to enter code it kept creating everything on one line at the formatting looked unreadable so here is a link:

http://jsfiddle.net/QFF4x/

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;" onmouseover="change(this)" onmouseout="restore(this)" ></div>
```

Either way, when the mouse is over the black line it expands downwards.
How can i make the onomouseover area larger?

For example if the mouse is hovering up to 15 pixels underneath the line the line would expand. how can i have it do that?

*Note: I everything has to be in the HTML, inline coding only I cannot link any JS or CSS pages.

Comment: I dont understand what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: *Note: I everything has to be in the HTML, inline coding only I cannot link any JS or CSS pages.* -- Ugh...why?

Comment: Also if you have a JSFiddle you should also include your code in the stack overflow question

Comment: I can't i dont know how... it does not work. And it has to be online inline coding because I am using a program to edit my website and the html is already built, I can't edit the code, I can only add HTML code segments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres a solution using a wrapping div with padding:-15px and on its hover events, just use the  firstElemntChild

```
<script>
    function change (element) {
        element.firstElementChild.style.border = "3px solid black";
    }
    function restore(element) {
        element.firstElementChild.style.border = "1px solid black";
    }
</script>

<div style="padding-bottom:15px;" onmouseout="restore(this)" onmouseover="change(this)" >

    <div style="border:1px solid black;"  >

    </div>

</div>
```

so you can hover 15 px under the border and the border changes and restores

fiddle . http://jsfiddle.net/QFF4x/2/

Comment: @Bodokh please, no! Don't use inline js!! Please read my answer again.

Comment: @Bodokh I see according to one of your other comments that you just want to use a program and don't care about the principles of good web coding. I presented you with something that also works but doesn't use bad practices. Other people may see this post and follow its example. By accepting this answer, you're giving more credibility to inline style and inline js, neither of which are necessary to solve your issue and both of which are bad practice - especially the inline js. Nonetheless...if you want what simply works without regard to its integrity, don't worry about it.

Comment: nevertheless,not using inline js has ONLY benefits for the developer and following developers (readability,reusuability/dry,seperating logic from output,...) theres absolutly nothing against it(as this code here is no business-logic) but i would prefer the plain css solution too.

Comment: @johnSmith yeah, I wouldn't have cared about it had he mentioned in the post that he's using a program to generate all of the code. Your solution makes sense knowing that, but that isn't clear in the question itself.

Comment: Obviously I would much prefer not to use inline JS and CSS but in this particular problem It was the only way. I always use style sheets it is much easier and also is more pleasant to the eye don't get me wrong. Either way many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I'm getting complaints about "external files" which isn't relevant, so I'm updating to clarify that all of this can be in one document: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/AbizuWa/3/edit)**

```
<style>
#outer {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#inner.big {
  border-width: 3px;
}
</style>

<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>

<script>

var outer = document.getElementById('outer');

var inner = document.getElementById('inner');

outer.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  inner.className = 'big';
});

outer.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  inner.className = '';
});

</script>
```

You don't need JavaScript for this at all. Here's just a css example: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/AbizuWa/1/edit)**

```
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.outer:hover > .inner {
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

Rather than using JavaScript, I'm using CSS `:hover`. The trick here is to wrap the element in another element and pad the outer element so that you can hover over that padding to affect the inner element.

If you do want to use JavaScript, **please** ignore any answers here using inline js (that's where you refer to javascript functions within the html.). Here's a basic example of how to do that without inline js and keeping your styles in css: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/AbizuWa/2/edit)**

```
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#outer {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#inner.big {
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var outer = document.getElementById('outer');

var inner = document.getElementById('inner');

outer.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  inner.className = 'big';
});

outer.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  inner.className = '';
});
```

Why do this instead of inline js? Read these results - there are plenty! https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F

Comment: He can't use external stylesheets.

Comment: Yeah it would be much simler in CSS but I wrote in the question I cannot use an external CSS or JS page, it has to be inline CSS, and i dont know how to add a hover feature in inline HTML.

Comment: @Bodokh None of this requires external anything.

Comment: What do you mean it doesen't it does! You have the HTML and CSS in different sheets! I need it all in one sheet.

Comment: @RCorrie Not does my answer require them. Whoever downvoted...that really sucks.

Comment: Wow this really got downvoted due to someone not understanding web technologies... Thats unfortunate. +1 for a complete and concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the border on hover change

```
element.style.border = "3px solid black";
```

To for 15px

```
element.style.border = "15px solid black";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the div in a larger div, and set the onclick event on the larger div.

```
<div onmouseover="change(this.childNodes[0])" onmouseout="restore(this.childNodes[0])">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution.

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;" onmouseover="javascript:this.style.border = '8px solid black';" onmouseout="javascript:this.style.border = '1px solid black';" ></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5GAUq/